# Crate and append rows based on average of previous rows and condition columns

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm working on a `dataframe` named `df` that contains a year of daily information for a float variable (`balance`) for many `account` values (used as main key). I'm trying to create a new column `expected_balance` by matching the date of previous months, calculating an average and using it as expected future value. I'll explain in detail now:
The dataset is generated after appending and parsing multiple json values, once I finish working on it, I get this:

```
              date  balance account  day  month  year   fdate
0      2018-04-13   470.57  SP014     13      4  2018  201804
1      2018-04-14   375.54  SP014     14      4  2018  201804
2      2018-04-15   375.54  SP014     15      4  2018  201804
3      2018-04-16   229.04  SP014     16      4  2018  201804
4      2018-04-17   216.62  SP014     17      4  2018  201804
...           ...      ...   ...  ...    ...   ...     ...
414857 2019-02-24   381.26  KO012     24      2  2019  201902
414858 2019-02-25   181.26  KO012     25      2  2019  201902
414859 2019-02-26   160.82  KO012     26      2  2019  201902
414860 2019-02-27     0.82  KO012     27      2  2019  201902
414861 2019-02-28   109.50  KO012     28      2  2019  201902
```

Each account value has 365 values (a starting date when the information was obtained and a year of info), resampled by day. After that, I'm splitting this dataframe into train and test. Train consists of all previous values except for the last 2 months of information and test are these last 2 months (the last month is not necesarilly full, if the last/max date value is `20-04-2019`, then `train will be from 20-04-2018 to 31-03-2019` and `test 01-03-2019 to 20-04-2019`). This is how I manage:

```
df_test_1 = df[df.fdate==df.groupby('account').fdate.transform('max')].copy()
dft = df.drop(df_test_1.index)
df_test_2 = dft[dft.fdate==dft.groupby('account').fdate.transform('max')].copy()
df_train = dft.drop(df_test_2.index)
df_test = pd.concat([df_test_2,df_test_1])
#print("Shape df: ",df.shape) #for validation purposes
#print("Shape test: ",df_test.shape) #for validation purposes
#print("Shape train: ",df_train.shape) #for validation purposes
```

What I need to do now is create a new column `exp_bal` (expected balance) for each date in the `df_test` that's calculated by averaging all train values for the particular day (this is the method requested so I **must** follow the instructions).
Here is an example of an expected output/result, I'm only printing account's AA001 values for a specific day for the last 2 ***train*** months (suppose these values always repeat for the other 8 months):

```
             date   balance account  day  month  year   fdate
...           ...       ...     ...  ...    ...   ...     ...
0      2019-03-20   200.00    AA000   20      3  2019  201903
1      2019-04-20   100.00    AA000   20      4  2019  201904
```

I should be able to use this information to append a new column for each day that is the average of the same day value for all months of `df_train`

```
             date   balance account  day  month  year   fdate exp_bal
0      2018-05-20   470.57    AA000   20      5  2018  201805  150.00
30     2019-06-20   381.26    AA000   20      6  2019  201906  150.00
```

So then I can calculate a mse for the that prediction for that account.

First of all I'm using this to iterate over each account:

```
ids = list(df['account'].unique())
for i in range(0,len(ids)):
    dft_train = df_train[df_train['account'] == ids[i]]
    dft_test = df_test[df_test['account'] == ids[i]] 
    first_date = min(dft_test['date'])
    last_date = max(df_ttest['date'])
    dft_train = dft_train.set_index('date')
    dft_test = dft_train.set_index('date')
```

And after this I'm lost on how to use the `dft_train` values to create this average for a given day that will be appended in a new column in `dft_test`.

I appreciate any help or suggestion, also feel free to ask for clarification/ more info, I'll gladly edit this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is for machine learing, right? have you thought about if that causes data leakage? especially if you add columns for dates that are after the date of the corresponding record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the only question you have with the above, but this is how to calculate the expected balance of the train data:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

# make test data
n = 60
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': np.tile(pd.date_range('2018-01-01',periods=n).values, 2), 'Account': np.repeat(['A', 'B'], n), 'Balance': range(2*n)})
df['Day'] = df.Date.dt.day

# calculate expected balance
df['exp_bal'] = df.groupby(['Account', 'Day']).Balance.transform('mean')

# example output for day 5
print(df[df.Day==5])
```

Output:

```
         Date Account  Balance  Day  exp_bal
4  2018-01-05       A        4    5     19.5
35 2018-02-05       A       35    5     19.5
64 2018-01-05       B       64    5     79.5
95 2018-02-05       B       95    5     79.5
```